# Get ID by query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, except

I have a stored procedure which has two parameters of `user-defined table type`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcedure
  @ReceivedBooks tp_Books READONLY,
  @ReceivedIdAuthors tp_Authors READONLY,
AS
```

The structure of user-defined table type looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tp_Books] AS TABLE(
    [BookName] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tp_Authors] AS TABLE(
    [AuthorIds] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
)
```

In addition, I have two tables `Books` and `Authors`:

`Books`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|      ID      |    Name                    |      Id_Author   |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       1      |     Hamlet                 |        1         | 
|       2      |     Spartaco               |        2         | 
|      10      |     Romeo and Juliet       |        1         | 
|      11      |     Great Expectations     |        3         | 
|      12      |     Pride and Prejudice    |        5         | 
|      13      |     A Tale of Two cities   |        3         | 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Authors`:

```
---------------------------------------------
|      ID      |    Name                    | 
---------------------------------------------
|       1      |     William Shakespeare    | 
|       2      |     Raffaello Giovagnoli   | 
|       3      |     Charles Dickens        | 
|       5      |     Jane Austin            |     
---------------------------------------------
```

For example, I receive `@ReceivedBooks` and `@idAuthors` with following values at my stored procedure:

```
 'Hamlet', 'Romeo and Juliet' --@ReceivedBooks
 1, 2, 3, 5                   --@ReceivedIdAuthors
```

then I can know that `1` is the `Id_Author` which I want to find. As the following `EXCEPT` statement returns no rows for `IdAuthor = 1`(William Shakespeare(`ID=1`) is an author of `Hamlet` and `Romeo and Juliet`). And `1` is the `idAuthor` of `Author` that I want to found   cause `EXCEPT` statement returns no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM @ReceivedBooks
EXCEPT 
SELECT Name FROM #Books WHERE IdAuthor IN (1)
```

Let me show an example, where `EXCEPT` statement returns rows. Consequently, this `Id_Author` is not what I want.

```
SELECT * FROM @ReceivedBooks
EXCEPT 
SELECT Name FROM #Books WHERE IdAuthor IN (2) -- 3, 5
```

So my goal is to find necessary `id_author` in `@ReceivedIdAuthors`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.  It seems unlikely that a `while` loop is necessary.

Comment: It would be better if you would explain your business need (and not your solution) in plain English.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please, be so kind to see my updated question.

Comment: @RogerWolf please, be so kind to see my updated question.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Except part of your query actually returns 2 results ('Hamlet' and 'Romeo and Juliet'), but the whole query (the except part applied to your first select statement) would return null. A question I have is, if your books in 'Received Books' are from two different authors, then the query would never return null, since you are only excluding books from one author at the time. Do you want to only get the name of an author if ALL books in your 'Received Books' list are written by the same author?

Comment: @A.Bremer Yeah, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on additional clarification comments, it seems all you really need is:

- To find whether all the books in your `@ReceivedBooks` parameter belong to the same author, and
- Whether a corresponding author is also present in the `@ReceivedIdAuthors` parameter.

The technique to use here is called [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)):

```
select b.Id_Author
from @ReceivedBooks rb
  inner join dbo.Books b on b.Name = rb.BookName
where exists (
  select 0 from @ReceivedIdAuthors ra
  where ra.AuthorId = b.Id_Author
)
group by b.Id_Author
having count(distinct b.Id_Author) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to return the first tuple of (person, department) where the person is not included in @List?

How big is @List? If is is fairly small you could just use:

```
SELECT dep.Name, 
       pr.ID
FROM dbo.Person AS pr
 INNER JOIN dbo.Department AS dep ON dep.ID = pr.id_Person
WHERE id_Person = @personId
 AND id_Person NOT IN @List
LIMIT 1;
```

Also, I don't think you need to iterate over the query, at least not given the data I can see in your problem description.

Comment: No, I would like to compare result of two queries which one is executed in iteration. And I want to get first `ID` when `EXPECT` returns no rows.